# How do I show, then hide the AppBar after a page loads?

Tags: c#, timer, winrt-xaml, appbar

After the page is visible to the user, I want the TopAppBar to show up for a second or two, then set IsOpen to false to close the AppBar. In essence I just want to briefly show the user the functionality I am hiding in the TopAppBar. I'm not sure where to place the code or how to implement the timer in XAML/C#.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, just call this function in the LoadState:

        private async void DelayedAppBarHide()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = true;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = false;

        }

Comment: please post it as an answer and choose it as your question's answer so other users can benefit from this question , too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out, just call this function in the LoadState:

```
    private async void DelayedAppBarHide()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = false;

    }
```